# Processing and examine user URLs in django

Tags: django, url, facebook-opengraph, fetch

I'm building a website where users are posting content and URLs, very much alike the facebook wall/news feed.

I was thinking that I could take the URL from the user and open it from the server in the django backend and examine the content (just like facebook does).

I thought that there should be a django-opengraph app which helps me to open a URL and check the meta-tags to determine what kind of content etc. But it seems that Open Graph is an invention of Facebook?

My question is how I can open a URL using django and fetch content (video, audio, images, texts) and by determine what kind of content i can embed it properly into my site? Any apps?

And also, I'm intersted in the security aspect of open URLs from the server sent by a user.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/ should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can request a url with urllib2 module. But I suggest using BeutifulSoup to check urls content. http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried BeautifulSoup and it seems what I need. I'm will download the page using a request, and then examine the html manually.

Answer (score 4):

[djangoembed](https://github.com/worldcompany/djangoembed) is no longer maintained. But you might want to take a look at [micawber](https://github.com/coleifer/micawber). It seems a good fit for your request.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I'll look into that! It seems intersting!

Answer (score 2):

The [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/) was indeed invented by Facebook and it's basically a set of metadata you can add to closely describe the page's content: 9GAG would describe the image that's being shown; YouTube would describe the video, etc. Most pages that provide the ability to share the content on Facebook are OGP friendly, but that still doesn't cover the entirety of the content available on the web.

In either case, be very careful if you go down the path of having your application itself retrieve and resolve content from URLs as others suggested. I'd much rather develop a JavaScript application that will utilize the client's resources to resolve the content itself, as there are many ways someone can feed you with malicious URLs that will purposefully exhaust your application's available resources if your not careful, not to mention that the process itself is very expensive to begin with.

Comment: That's what I was concerned about, it's very expensive in performance and also open for security breaches. But loading everything on client-side would look a bit weired graphically if you have a lot of posts...

Comment: At least make sure you're protected from the two common DoS attacks: being bombarded with large responses that need a lot of memory allocated to construct the nodal representation or end points that simulate unstable connections, intentionally prolonging the time your application spends reading the response. Thorougly examine the `urllib2` module to understand the request variants and how you can configure them to avoid some common pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the existing responses: Download the page using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and then process it with [beautifulsoup4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

#### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://www.facebook.com')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print soup.title.string
```

Which would return

`Welcome to Facebook - Log In, Sign Up or Learn More`

See the beautifulsoup documentation on how to pull out other elements from the html.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple answer for this. Using just requests or urllib2, you can make some guesses on the structure and grab the title or guess what the content may be of a news article / video. Instead of reinventing the wheel, there are two solutions that I know of to get you off the ground running.

1. [Embed.ly](http://embed.ly), which is a paid service and has a very nice API.
2. [djangoembed](https://github.com/worldcompany/djangoembed). A free solution using the oEmbed protocol. Although I haven't used this, it seems like exactly what you need.